Get category path including parent categories
I'm trying to retrieve the category path including parent categories too
I'm trying to use the following code to retrieve the current category and parent categories further up the tree to display categories in a breadcrumb format such as:

TV / LED / 4K / 50 inch

<?php 
 function retrieve_category_path($id){
     
     // DB connection
    require("../../config/db/connection.php");
    // Company ID
    $company_id = 1 
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, parent, position FROM category WHERE company_id = ? AND id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $company_id, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    $path = array();
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $parent =$row['parent'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $position = $row['position'];
            $position_seperator = '::';
            $seperator = '/';
                if($parent > 0){
                    $path[] = array($name, $position_seperator, $position, $seperator); // Category 1::2/Category 2::3/Category 3::1/Category 4::0/ 
                    $path = array_merge(retrieve_category_path($row['parent']), $path);
                } else {
                    $path = array($name, $position_seperator, $position, $seperator); // Category 1::2/Category 2::3/Category 3::1/Category 4::0/                   
                }
        }
    return $path;
 }
?>

However the returned data for categories that have more than one category are displaying as an array rather than a string
Using
$get_data = retrieve_category_path($data); //$data is the category ID i use to send to the function
$category_path = implode($get_data);

Results in:

TV/ArrayArrayArray

Rather than

TV / LED / 4K / 50 inch

Please could someone point out where i'm going wrong, i'm guessing its in the $path section of the function

Just a tip: If you have to explain your variable name with a comment then perhaps you should rename your variable? A better name for $data would probably be $categoryId. Everything is "data" so that's a bad name to start with.

This function doesn't feel like it really needs to be recursive. It might be easier to just loop and replace $id with $row['parent'] each time, building $path as you go.

You're producing a nested array in this line $path[] = array($name, $position_seperator, $position, $seperator);. Therefore for layer 2 and deeper it will be an array. Try to change this line to $path = array($name, $position_seperator, $position, $seperator);
